# Creating an ArrayList from superclass but containing objects from extended classes

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have 3 classes. Contact, EmailContact, and PhoneContact. I want to create an Arraylist that can contain objects from both EmailContact and PhoneContact. And i need to find a way to get those objects. Here is what i have so far but It doesn't seem to split them like i wanted to.

```
    public void addEmailContact(String date, String email) {
        ArrayList<Contact> con = new ArrayList<>();
        con.add(new Contact(date, email));
    }

    public void addPhoneContact(String date, String phone) {
        ArrayList<Contact> con = new ArrayList<>();
        con.add(new Contact(date, phone));
    }
```

Comment: You can do that if there `is-a` relationship between them

Comment: if `EmailContact ` and `PhoneContact ` extend `Contact ` you can just add them to the `ArrayList<Contact>` list

Comment: con.add(new EmailContact(date, email)); instead

Comment: @TrungNTNguyen Thank you for this.

Comment: what do you want to do with the array content? as it will be awkward when retrieving objects because you will not really know if it's an EmailContact or PhoneContact, and more so you will not be able to use the `getEmail` respectively `getPhone` methods, only if you explicitly cast the contacts retrieved to their expected Class, which will often raise an `ClassCastException`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcards are here to help you. One can add any class that extends `Contact` class to a list which accepts  `? super Contact`

```
List<? super Contact> list= new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new EmailContact());
list.add(new PhoneContact());
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Do you know how can i get them separately in different methods?

Comment: Both methods need to share same list, take it as a parameter or declare it as instance variable

Comment: @nits.kk can you elaborate a bit please? I'm new to java and don't quite understand your logic.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Contact {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<? super Contact>  list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new PContact());
        list.add(new EContact());

    }
}

class PContact extends Contact{

}
class EContact extends Contact{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basic polymorphism in action. Reference can be of super type but it can refer to object of any sub type. The keyword `new` instantiates an Object. You need to provide the actual implementation with new. In your case

```
 Contact con = new PhoneContact(date, phone);
 Contact anotherCon = new EmailContact(date, email);
```

So now with ArrayList you can do as below.

```
List<Contact> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new EmailContact(date,email);
list.add(new PhoneContact(date,phone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the hierarchy :

```
abstract class Contact { }

class EmailContact extends Contact { }

class PhoneContact extends Contact { }
```

you can do the following :

```
List<? super Contact> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(new EmailContact());
myList.add(new PhoneContact());
```

The wildcard signifies that you can add any class that *extends* `Contact` to the list.

Do note that when you fetch an element from `myList`, the only guarantee is that it will return a *type* of `Object`. So do not try to cast it without checking the right *instance* of `Contact` otherwise you will end up with a *ClassCastException*.

For eg:

```
Object contact = myList.get(0);        
if (contact instanceof EmailContact) {
    EmailContact emailContact = (EmailContact) contact;
} else if (contact instanceof PhoneContact) {
    PhoneContact phoneContact = (PhoneContact) contact;
}
```